# pass a column in a temptable to a stored procedure as a parameter?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which usually takes only one value per parameter at a time.

```
USE [BannerLink] 
GO 

DECLARE @return_value int 
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo [BannerSummaryReportNoTag]
                        @BannerID = 31606,
                        @TagName = 'SOSEnglishIBVNoCover'
```

Now I have a temptable with multiple BannerIDs and Tagnames. I was wondering if there was a way to populate stored procedure with data from a temptable. So the PSEUDO CODE is someting like this

```
USE [BannerLink] 
GO 

DECLARE @return_value int 
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[BannerSummaryReportNoTag]
                        @BannerID = #tmptable1.BannerID,
                        @TagName = #tmptable1.TagName
```

The code above does not work obviously but im wondering how I can do this in `SQL Server`. Thanks!

Comment: `SQL` is the standard that most RDBMS implement (to varying degrees). `SQL Server` is Microsoft's RDBMS.

Comment: what about XML ? Is it a viable alternative ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best Solution would be to use Table Type Parameter, alternatively you would need a performance killer cursor , something like this...

```
USE [BannerLink] 
GO 

DECLARE @return_value INT
       ,@BannerID     INT
       ,@TagName      VARCHAR(1000)


DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY FOR  
SELECT BannerID , TagName
FROM   #tmptable1

OPEN cur   
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @BannerID, @TagName


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
EXEC  @return_value = [dbo].[BannerSummaryReportNoTag]
                      @BannerID = @BannerID
                     ,@TagName  = @TagName

       FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @BannerID, @TagName  
END   

CLOSE cur   
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `Table Type`. Create type:

```
CREATE TYPE MyTableType AS TABLE 
( TagName VARCHAR(50)
, BannerID INT );
```

Alter your proc:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BannerSummaryReportNoTag]
@Banners MyTableType READONLY
AS
....
```

Call it:

```
DECLARE @T MyTableType
INSER INTO t VALUES ...

EXEC [dbo].[BannerSummaryReportNoTag] @Banners = @t
```

Comment: what if you are unable to alter the procedure?

Comment: No way, unfortunately

Comment: Ahh the good old catch 22 of the all powerful DBA. Thanks, got some new knowledge today!

Comment: @vmedhe2, but if you mean in your question that you just want to call proc for each row in your table than see Ali's answer

Comment: Yes that answered my question fully. Thanks for your help as well.